# How to install a library for a single project

Tags: library

How do you install an Arduino library so it's only available for a specific project?

Say I have a codebase located at /myproject, and I want to install libraries at /myproject/lib/somelib. I can't find how to make `arduino myproject.ino` find the libraries under ./lib.

Googling "installing Arduino libraries" only finds me examples of [installing libraries globally](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries) (and through the GUI no less), which is horrible practice and guarantees version conflicts.

When I used `ino`, it supported a local ./lib directory, but I can't find any equivalent feature in `arduino`.

Comment: I don't think you can "install a library for a single project". A workaround is to simply copy all the header and source files of the library into the sketch folder, as if they were other source files.

Comment: Doesn't `#include lib/somelib/libheader.h` work?

Comment: @Gerben, Not for me. Arduino only seems to be able to find includes in the current directory or in one of the expected system library paths.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to [ano](https://github.com/scottdarch/Arturo), which supports a local `lib` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You want to switch to my [UECIDE](http://uecide.org/beta) for that functionality. You can then place libraries inside a folder called *libraries* in your sketch folder.

You also get the benefits of a much improved IDE :)